# ASP.Net Configuration Tool Windows 8 issues

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Ever since I updated to Windows 8 I have noticed that while using the .NET configuration tool's security tab, when I try to add or manage users I recieve "Cannot connect to Database" error. The other parts work just fine apart from the fact that they are too slow.

I carried the same project to a Windows 7 PC and encountered no errors. I checked the firewall settings and saw no difference.

What could be the reason? Both my windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012 is up-to-date. Is this a firewall issue and I have to allow a specific port?

Comment: _"Is this a firewall issue and I have to allow a specific port?"_ - don't go guessing. Compare the old and new situation. Where was the old user database located, on your Windows 7 machine? Did you reinstall it on Windows 8? What error does it log exactly?

Comment: The database is hosted, the only difference is the operationg systems. The error log lists some errors and some functions of this page regarding ;
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles\Security\Users\addUser.aspx

Comment: Then investigate those some errors. :-)

Comment: Sorry I phrased it wrong, The error is cannot connect the database and c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles\Security\Users\addUser.aspx is listed as the path. I checked them in windows 7 and 8 but saw no difference yet on one it works, on the other one it doesn't.

Comment: _"cannot connect the database"_ - then troubleshoot that. Connection strings, permissions, that sort of things. The exact error message and SQL server error code might help.